# NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm from android-maps-utils use pixel or dp on constructor params?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-3

The class [NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/c1158e8ab54d2abe032bca3a87cbc3756ed47709/library/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm.java) from [googlemaps/android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) have a constructor:

```
 public NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        mViewWidth = screenWidth;
        mViewHeight = screenHeight;
    }
```

But Im not sure if I should send the width in pixels or in dp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure all of the Google android map parts work in raw pixels, not dip.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm class (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/main/library/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm.java):

```
/**
 * @param screenWidth  map width in dp
 * @param screenHeight map height in dp
 */
public NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
    mViewWidth = screenWidth;
    mViewHeight = screenHeight;
}
```